# Unexpected Error in Instruments using UIAutomation

Tags: iphone, ios4, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I am currently using IOS SDK 4.0.2 and learning how to do UIAutomation. Unfortunately I found that in the Simulator, when I try running a simple Java script test (that just assigns variables) I get the following error.

```
Unexpected error in -[UIATarget_0x5d04f60 frontMostApp], /SourceCache/UIAutomation_Sim/UIAutomation-37/Framework/UIATargetElements.m line 437,
```

Here is the "Script" I was trying to run

```
   function iDontDoAnything() {
      var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
      var app = target.frontMostApp();
      var navBar = app.navigationBar();
      UIALogger.logPass("it passed");
}

  UIALogger.logStart("First Tester Test");
  iDontDoAnything();
```

And I figured out that this is because I am getting a null returned when frontMostApp() is called. The test runs fine/passes on the actual device with 4.0.2.

Main Question: Is there a way to solve this problem in 4.0.2 on the simulator? I have noted a solution for the earlier version (4.0.1) that had this problem - tried it with no success.

Not much documentation out there yet, any advice would be much appreciated!

Lauren

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate of [Can we use UI Automation tools with the iPhone Simulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397733/can-we-use-ui-automation-tools-with-the-iphone-simulator) because I just tried the solution listed there and it works with 4.0.2.  You need to remember to copy the property list to the 4.0.2 simulator directory and restart the Simulator afterwards.

Comment: Thanks- I thought I had tried this but must have copied it to the incorrect directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check if simulator has the accessibity.plist?

I found this on https://devforums.apple.com/message/261883#261883 they recommend: "Copy ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Accessibility.plist to ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0.1/Library/Preferences" and it worked for me.